# How to execute onclick before navigating to a different page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am working in React and I have the following scenario.

```
  <a href={link} variant="primary" onClick={this.onClickDoSomething}>
                          here.
  </a>
```

Now, I want the onclick to execute before the link has been clicked. However I do not see it happening.

How to work around this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: remove the link from href and first handle onclick event after that redirect page to given link

Comment: the onclick should fire, my guess it is more of an issue what the onclick is doing.

Comment: I've got pretty much identical code and everything works fine for me.... onClick is firing and AFTER the browser will automatically navigate to the link's url.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `onclick()` will fire before the page is redirected. It appears that you may want to handle your navigation within your `onclick` function as opposed to having an `href` attribute. By doing it this way you can conditionally redirect (if need be) and/or wait for some async code to complete.

```js
onClick = url => {
  alert('Do something');
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="onClick('https://stackoverflow.com')">here.</a>
```

React snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  onClickDoSomething = link => ev => {
    alert(link);
    // Do any operations here
    window.location.href = link;
  }
  render() {
    const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
    return <div>
      <a href='#' onClick={this.onClickDoSomething(link)}>here.</a> 
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but here does not 'appear' clickable to the use?

Comment: you could throw in the attribute `href='#'` to get the styling if you would like

Comment: Updated my answer, also provided you with a React example

Answer (score 0):

your click handler should be like this

```
onClickDoSomething=(link)=>{
//do something,then redirect to given link
window.location.href=link

}
```

and you should render link as

```
<a  variant="primary" onClick={()=>{this.onClickDoSomething(link)}}>
                      here.
</a>
```

Comment: Does cmd+click or ctrl+click default browser behavior still work using this solution?

Comment: yes it will work with cmd+click and ctrl+click,but since no href is set it will open blank window when ctrl+click used

Comment: Thanks for the response, If I put the link in the anchor's href it works fine and I don't need to do the manual window.location.href navigation.  It runs the JS and then will automatically navigate. (tested in chrome, FF, and safari)

Comment: have never checked like that, thanks for sharing info,but OP has already done this and he says its not working , if you see code in the quesiton he has given href and click handler to anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

First will suggest use react router 
but if link is external then another way is keep href="#" and write onclickHandler function at the end onclickHandler just use 
window.location=[link]

you want to visit

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

All the given answers (i.e. using # for the href then adding window.location to your click handler) should work perfectly.

However, in case you're looking for another solution, you can also try making the link a button instead of an anchor tag, and just styling it as a button. Below I've done so using Bootstrap, but you could do so with just plain CSS as well:

```js
handleClickExamQuestions =  function(URL){               
   window.location=URL       
 }
```

```html
 <button class="btn btn-link" onClick = {()=>this.handleClick(URL)}>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React-Router-Dom ^6.10, and using `<Link/>` tag, I do function call before a redirect like this:

```
<Link
  className="navBtn"
  to="/"
  onClick={() => setNavOpen(false)}>  //HERE
     <h2>Home</h2>
 </Link>
```

**OnClick** gets executed, where I close my Navbar before redirecting to another page.