# React <Link> to use both href and onClick

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I want to use `<a>` with both an `href` and `onClick` such that my code fully executes the passed `onClick` handler before redirecting to the `href` value:

Example:

```js
const Link = ({ children, ...props }) => <a {...props}>{children}</a>;

const someTask = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
};

export default App = () => (
  <Link href="https://stackoverflow.com" onClick={someTask}>
    Click me
  </Link>
);
```

Currently, the above will not log all numbers up to 1000 before redirecting. For me, ~180 numbers are logged before the redirect occurs.

I do **not** want a solution that sets `href="#"` and handles the redirect inside the `onClick`. This is because of accessibility reasons where my `<a>` needs to have a clear `href` attribute value.

Some similar posts I've looked into:

- [How to execute onclick before navigating to a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798300/how-to-execute-onclick-before-navigating-to-a-different-page)
  Suggests handling everything inside the `onClick` and not having an `href`
- [HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)
  Suggests having the `onClick` handler return true or false whether to allow the `href`, but React doesn't allow this syntax https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

I am open to other approaches as long as the generated `<a>` has an honest `href` and executes its `onClick` handler fully.

Comment: what about using `preventDefault` and `stopImmediatePropagation`, and at the end of the task doing something like `window.location.href = event.target.href`?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I Tried setting `e.preventDefault(); e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` at the start of the task, and then `window.location.href = e.target.href` at the end. It still logs only around ~200 numbers before redirecting

Comment: You shouldn't focus on console.log not finishing its job. Console.log is slow and probably asynchronous, i.e. it doesn't wait for the text being effectively written before returning, so to stay apparently fast.
If you can't return true or false in your onclick handler, then preventDefault should work, given that you don't run anything asynchronous in your onclick handler.